# Como substituir {vars} em uma string?

Tags: c#, string, regex, interpolação-de-string

Eu tenho uma string

```
string str = "Bem vindo {Usuario}. Agora são: {Horas}";
```

Quero substituir `{Usuario}` por um nome e `{Horas}` pelo horário atual, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma idéia é usar um `IFormattable` que entende os seus formatos. Por exemplo, se você tem uma classe assim:

```
class Modelo : IFormattable {
  public string Usuario { get; set; }
  public DateTime Horas { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
  public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) {
    if (format == "Usuario") return Usuario;
    if (format == "Horas") return Horas.ToString();
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

Você pode usá-la dessa forma:

```
var modelo = new Modelo { Usuario = "Lobo" };
var strFinal = string.Format("Bem vindo {0:Usuario}. Agora são: {0:Horas}", modelo);
```

Note que você ainda precisa utilizar o índice do objeto que fará a substituição (no caso, `0`).

Você pode implementar `IFormattable` usando reflexão, por exemplo, para substituir qualquer propriedade do objeto.

Answer (score 8):

No C# 6 existe um novo recurso de interpolação de *string* em que, dependendo do objetivo, é possível deixar tudo isto de lado e deixar a linguagem/*framework* cuidar disto para você, portanto não as demais respostas não fazem sentido mais em C# moderno, ainda que, claro, funcione. Então usando:

```
string str = $"Bem vindo {Usuario}. Agora são: {Horas}"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/InterpolationSimple.cs).

Já conseguirá o resultado desejado desde que no momento da avaliação da *string* você tenha as variáveis `Usuario` e `Horas` no escopo.

Leia [mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101).

Answer (score 7):

O C# já tem uma função para isto, se chama [`String.Format` veja a documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
String.Format("Bem vindo {0}. Agora são: {1}", usuario, hora);
```

Entretanto se você quiser implementar algo similar, você pode utilizar `Regex` da seguinte maneira

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"{(?<Parametro>[^}]+)}", m =>
{
    string variavel = m.Groups["Parametro"].Value; // Usuario, Horas
    switch (variavel)
    {
        case "Usuario": return usuario;
        case "Horas": return hora;
    }
    return "";
});
```

A sintaxe `(?<SomeName>.*)` significa que isto é um [grupo nomeado, veja a documentação aqui.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#named_matched_subexpression)

Isso permite que você acesse grupos específicos capturados, através de `match.Groups["NomeDoGrupo"].Value`.

Desta forma você pode capturar os *tokens* e substitui-los como desejar.

Apesar deste modo ser possível, eu **sugiro utilizar o `String.Format` que foi bem pensado, validado e é o padrão para este tipo de operação**.

Comment: O `{` e o `}` têm significado especial na sintaxe da regex (ex: `a{3,5}`). É permitido inserir eles sem nenhum tipo de *escape* assim?

Comment: Assim como `-` tem um significado especial (`[a-z]`) ele só tem esse significado no contexto especifico. Portanto não é necessário o _escape_.

Answer (score 3):

Se a sua chave "{Usuario}" for fixa, talvez seja melhor simplesmente fazer uma substituição de texto ao invés de utilizar expressões regulares. As ERs são muito bacanas e poderosas, mas há um certo custo computacional a ser pago.

Com um teste bem simples utilizando a sugestão de ER oferecida pelo @BrunoLM (que aliás, foi uma sugestão bem bacana), dá pra perceber que a diferença de tempo de processamento é bastante considerável:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string replace1(string str)
        {
            var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"{(?<Parametro>[^}]+)}", m =>
            {
                string variavel = m.Groups["Parametro"].Value; // Usuario, Horas
                switch (variavel)
                {
                    case "Usuario": return "Fulano da Silva";
                    case "Horas": return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                }
                return "";
            });
            return result;
        }

        static string replace2(string str)
        {
            str = str.Replace("{Usuario}", "Beltrano da Silva");
            str = str.Replace("{Horas}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"));
            return str;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str = "Bem vindo {Usuario}. Agora são: {Horas}";

            DateTime dStart = DateTime.Now;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Resultado 1: " + Program.replace1(str));
            DateTime dEnd = DateTime.Now;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Duração: " + (dEnd - dStart).TotalMilliseconds);

            dStart = DateTime.Now;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Resultado 2: " + Program.replace2(str));
            dEnd = DateTime.Now;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Duração: " + (dEnd - dStart).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Produz a seguinte saída (duração em milisegundos):

```
Resultado 1: Bem vindo Fulano da Silva. Agora são: 15:28:15
Duração: 9,0005
Resultado 2: Bem vindo Beltrano da Silva. Agora são: 15:28:15
Duração: 1
```

Comment: Um *benchmark* de uma única repetição não quer dizer muito. Seria necessário fazer um loop para contar pelo menos 1 segundo. Além disso é interessante repetir o benchmark inteiro mais de uma vez (no mesmo programa) para evitar que tempo de "aquecimento" seja contado (como inicializar *buffers* de saída). Outro ponto é não *printar* o resultado dentro do benchmark para não incluir esse processamento (pode ser bem imprevisível). Só mais um ponto: compare coisas iguais. Um dos casos substitui mais caracteres que o outro.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal: Você tem toda razão, mas a minha intenção era apenas ilustrar que de fato 'podem haver diferenças'. Se o cenário for simples como pareceu, usar ER *pode* ser um exagero. Há muita discussão sobre isso, na verdade. Por exemplo, nessa thread e links referenciados: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380062/is-using-a-regular-expression-faster-than-indexof