# O que significa o simbolo "$" antes de uma string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, interpolação-de-string

Visualizando um código aqui no SOpt, notei a utilização do simbolo "$" e fiquei com dúvida sobre sua utilização.

- O que é o simbolo "$" antes de uma *string*?
- Para que ele serve?
- Por que utilizá-lo?

#### Exemplo

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = " Hello World ";
        WriteLine($"Corta o fim: |{texto.TrimEnd()}|");
        WriteLine($"Corta o início: |{texto.TrimStart()}|");
        WriteLine($"Corta ambos: |{texto.Trim()}|");
        WriteLine($"Corta tudo: |{texto.Replace(" ", "")}|");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Isso chama-se *string interpolation*.

Em C# 6 existe este símbolo para indicar uma condição especial daquele literal *string*. Com a interpolação de *string*, podemos usar uma variável ou uma expressão dentro da *string*. Para isto o compilador precisa entender que isto está sendo usado nela, ou seja, que é um literal especial. Sem o símbolo o compilador vai interpretar o literal como um texto qualquer e não tomará nenhuma ação específica.

É uma forma de evitar a concatenação de *strings*. Também evita a passagem de um argumento para a *string* ser formatada:

```
WriteLine($"Contei {x} vezes");
WriteLine("Contei {0} vezes", x);
WriteLine("Contei " + x.ToString() + " vezes");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vevtql). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vU1j5X). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/InterpolationIntrodution.cs).

## Comparando as formas

Qual é a melhor forma?

A concatenação é certamente a pior e deve ser evitada, há ou havia poucos casos que ela era útil. Uma vantagem que ela tinha é que muitas vezes era mais rápido concatenar do que formatar uma *string* colocando o conteúdo dentro.

A diferença de sintaxe fica mais evidente fora do `Write`:

```
var texto = $"Contei {x} vezes";
var texto = string.Format("Contei {0} vezes", x);
```

A primeira é mais simples e mantêm o fluxo de leitura. Você vê a expressão que será usada para inserir dentro do texto no exato local onde ela será inserida. Com a formatação (segundo exemplo) você tem que olhar à frente qual será o argumento a ser usado. E se tiver vários, usar algum argumento repetidas vezes, terá que ficar contando para descobrir o que entra aonde.

Note que o compilador avalia o que está dentro da interpolação. Aquilo não é tratado como uma parte do texto e sim como parte do código. Qualquer código válido em C# pode ser usado.

## Ela não resolve tudo

A segunda, a *string* de formatação, não está descartada. Ela tem a vantagem de ser resolvida em tempo de execução. Muitas vezes é o que se deseja. Um exemplo típico são as mensagens de internacionalização. Você pode ter textos que podem estar em várias línguas. Dentro deste texto deve entrar uma variável que a aplicação vai colocar na hora de executar. Isto só será resolvido em tempo de execução, portanto a interpolação de texto está descartada.

Vamos dizer que tenha em um arquivo externo ou banco de dados o seguinte texto: `Minha idade é {idade}` E exista um método que pega ele no arquivo, assim:

```
var idade = 25;
var exemplo = GetLocalText("My age is"); //retorna o texto "Minha idade é {idade}"
var texto = $exemplo; //isto não funciona, não é um literal.
```

Este texto da variável `exemplo` vindo de fora da aplicação não é de conhecimento do compilador. O `idade` aí dentro do texto nunca foi compilado, então a variável não pode ser colocada no lugar deste texto.

A solução seria guardar a *string* diferente (`Minha idade é {0}`) e passar um argumento para ela.

```
var idade = 25;
var exemplo = GetLocalText("My age is"); //retorna o texto acima
var texto = string.Format(exemplo, idade); //produzirá "Minha idade é 25".
```

Evidentemente se você for repetir uma expressão dentro do texto provavelmente vale à pena executá-la antes guardando em uma variável e usar apenas a variável.

## Informações extras

[Documentação com exemplo e outras formas de formatação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Um exemplo de como fica melhor junto com outras funcionalidades do ASP.NET Core.

Antigo:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index",
    "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Novo:

```
<a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.GetUserName()!</a>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/InterpolationMix.cs).

[Retirado desse artigo](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2422807).

Para obter este resultado internamente há uma interpolação.

Em futura versão do C# (talvez a 10) deve ter a interpolação de *string* constante que é uma otimização que eu esperava desde da 6.

Comment: +1. Eu nunca tinha usado esse *feature*. Vivendo e aprendendo.