# O que significa duas chaves no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, interpolação-de-string

Entendi o "===" que testa valor e tipo, diferente do "==" que testa apenas valor, porém não entendi a dupla chave, tipo: `{{alguma_coisa}}`, por exemplo em um JavaScript que possuo, tem algo assim:

```
mozL10n.get('page_of', {pageCount: pagesCount}, 'de {{pageCount}}');
```

Há mesmo a necessidade das duas chaves?

Comment: Parece ser a notação de algum framework, talvez o angularjs

Comment: "l10n" significa *localization*, artigo relacionado: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n#l10n

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Isto é específico desta [API não padrão](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mozL10n). Evite usá-la.

É um *placeholder*. É usado para produzir uma interpolação de *string*, ainda que use uma forma mais simples. É muito parecido com o `{0}` usado em C#, mas um pouco melhor porque a expressão pode ser usada dentro da *string*, como na [interpolação de *string* do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101). Esta expressão será avaliada e o seu resultado é que será impresso neste local.

As chaves duplas foram escolhidas para evitar alguma ambiguidade, poderia ser qualquer outra coisa. O importante é ter algum caractere que marque início e fim da expressão e que seja algo pouco usado em textos normais, para evitar ter que escapar e imprimir isto de forma normal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vale a pena adicionar que no ECMA Script 6 haverá um recurso padrão semelhante, porém con sintaxe diferente. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 8):

Neste exemplo:

```
var a = {};
console.log(a);
```

Ele é utilizado apenas para inicializar um objeto sem nenhum valor no mesmo.

No seu Exemplo:

```
mozL10n.get('page_of', {pageCount: pagesCount}, 'de {{pageCount}}');
```

Ele é utilizado como um padrão de `template` para identificação de valores que serão modificados, isto não é do javascript e sim uma convenção da sua API.

Comment: Entendi ambos, Gabriel e bigown. Um placeholder como disse o bigown.

Comment: Que é substituído por um valor ok, o que eu não estava entendendo é a utilização de duas chaves, achei que pudesse ser alguma novidade em versões mais recentes do javascript.

Comment: @pnet é interessante você especificar qual framework você esta utilizando para que nos possamos responder de forma mais especifica, pelo menos no novo javascript ES6 não tem nada de novo sobre isto.

Comment: Vocês já responderam a razão da dupla chave.