# Como manipular propriedades de instâncias de uma classe que está em uma List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Tenho uma classe chamada `Pessoa`, está classe possui duas propriedades `Nome` e `Idade`, eu estou utilizando uma `List<T>` para manipular dados, sei que posso manipular dados do tipo `string` ou `int` criando uma `List<string> listStr` ou uma `List<int> listInt`. E se eu quiser inserir um valor novo do tipo de dado correspondente à lista criada basta utilizar o método `Add()`. Por exemplo:

```
listStr.Add("Minha Lista 1");
```

E também para o tipo `int`:

```
listInt.Add(50);
```

Entretanto não sei como acessar e inserir valores nas propriedades `Nome` e `Idade` em instâncias da minha classe `Pessoa` que estão em uma `List<Pessoa>`, tentei usar o método `ListPessoa.Add()`, porem ele parece aceitar somente objetos do tipo `Pessoa`. Abaixo segue um exemplo como ilustração do problema:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListaObjeto
{
    class Pessoa 
    {
        private String nome;
        private int idade;

        public Pessoa()
        {
            this.nome = String.Empty;
            this.idade = 0;
        }

        public Pessoa(string nome, int idade)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.idade = idade;
        }

        public string Nome
        {
            get { return this.nome; }
            set { this.nome = value; }
        }

        public int Idade
        {
            get { return this.idade; }
            set { this.idade = value; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Pessoa> ListaPessoa = new List<Pessoa>();
            // Como acessar as propriedades Nome e Idade das instância de Pessoa que estão na ListaPessoa?            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma instância de `Pessoa` e passa-la para o método `Add` da sua `List<Pessoa>`.

Veja nesse exemplo como realizo algumas operações com sua `List<Pessoa>`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Pessoa> ListaPessoa = new List<Pessoa>();

        // Adicionando algumas pessoas para serem manipuladas no exemplo

        ListaPessoa.Add(new Pessoa
        {
            Nome = "Pessoa 1",
            Idade = 18
        });

        ListaPessoa.Add(new Pessoa
        {
            Nome = "Pessoa 2",
            Idade = 25
        });

        ListaPessoa.Add(new Pessoa
        {
            Nome = "Pessoa 3",
            Idade = 31
        });

        // Acessando e alterando os valores de uma pessoa que já está na lista

        // Obtém a instância da "Pessoa 2", note que estou acessando as instâncias da lista da mesma maneira que faço com um array
        var pessoa = ListaPessoa[1];

        Console.WriteLine($"Nome: {pessoa.Nome}, Idade: {pessoa.Idade}");
        // Saída: Nome: Pessoa Pessoa 2, Idade: 25

        // Alterando valores da pessoa obtida
        pessoa.Nome = "Pessoa X";
        pessoa.Idade = 99;

        Console.WriteLine($"Nome: {pessoa.Nome}, Idade: {pessoa.Idade}");
        // Saída: Nome: Pessoa X, Idade: 99
    }
}
```

[Clique aqui para visualizar este mesmo exemplo em execução no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kgjdZB)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que criar um novo objeto desta classe e adicioná-lo à lista:

```
listaPessoa.Add(new Pessoa("João", 18));
```

Completo:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ListaObjeto {
    public class Pessoa {
        public Pessoa() {
            Nome = "";
            Idade = 0;
        }

        public Pessoa(string nome, int idade) {
            Nome = nome;
            Idade = idade;
        }

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int Idade { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            var listaPessoa = new List<Pessoa>();
            listaPessoa.Add(new Pessoa("João", 18));
            listaPessoa.Add(new Pessoa());
            foreach (var pessoa in listaPessoa) WriteLine($"Nome: {pessoa.Nome} - Idade {pessoa.Idade}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ds7hmg). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rqKDUF). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ChangeItem.cs). Modernizei o código.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Pare que serve o caracter $ antes da string?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho o caractere `$` faz parte de uma nova funcionalidade da versão 6 do C#, essa funcionalidade se chama [interpolação de strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). A criação de uma "string interpolada" funciona de uma maneira muito parecida com o criação uma string através do método `string.Format` e consegue gerar o mesmo resultado só que através de um código mais legível e fácil de escrever.

Comment: A sim, eu tentei usar aqui mais o compilador apontou erro, estou usando o visual studio 2012.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101