# Erro operador não pode ser aplicado ao grupo de método

Tags: c#, .net, classes, método

Estou tentando imprimir uma subtração de datas usando C# com WebForms, porém não sei como inserir corretamente os atributos nos métodos nem como imprimir o método.

Eu estou convertendo a subtração das datas em dias, pois não sei trabalhar direito com o `DateTime`, não sei se tem como fazer isso diretamente.

Após a conversão da diferença entre a data menos e a data maior em dias eu insiro esses dias em um novo `DateTime` que eu chamei de total. Então eu mando imprimir o total em dias, meses e anos separadamente. Só que quando eu chamo no método de Impressão que se chama `ImprimirExperiênciasTravalho()` o IDE acusa que essa operação não é permitida.

O resultado que eu esperava dessa classe seria a impressão da empresa, do cargo, a descrição das obrigações da pessoa na empresa e quando a pessoa inserir data de entrada na empresa e saída, essa impressão exibiria o tempo total que a pessoa trabalhou nessa empresa.

O erro que está dando é esse aqui: [image: Imagem do Erro]

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand od type 'strig' and 'method group'

Segue abaixo o código C#:

```
public class Experiencias_Trabalho
{
    private string nomeEmpresa, cargo, descricaoFuncao;
    private DateTime dataInicio = new DateTime();
    private DateTime dataSaida = new DateTime();

    public Experiencias_Trabalho(string nomeEmpresa, string cargo, string descricaoFuncao, DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataSaida)
    {
        this.nomeEmpresa = nomeEmpresa;
        this.cargo = cargo;
        this.descricaoFuncao = descricaoFuncao;
        this.DataInicio = dataInicio;
        this.DataSaida = dataSaida;
    }

    public string NomeEmpresa
    {
        get
        {
            return nomeEmpresa;
        }

        set
        {
            nomeEmpresa = value;
        }
    }

    public string Cargo
    {
        get
        {
            return cargo;
        }

        set
        {
            cargo = value;
        }
    }

    public string DescricaoFuncao
    {
        get
        {
            return descricaoFuncao;
        }

        set
        {
            descricaoFuncao = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime DataInicio
    {
        get
        {
            return dataInicio;
        }

        set
        {
            dataInicio = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime DataSaida
    {
        get
        {
            return dataSaida;
        }

        set
        {
            dataSaida = value;
        }
    }

    public static string TempoTotal(DateTime DataInicio, DateTime DataSaida)
    {
        System.TimeSpan diff = DataSaida - DataInicio;
        int diasTotais = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalDays);
        DateTime total = new DateTime().AddDays(diasTotais);
        return (total.Year - 1) + " anos, " + (total.Month % 12) + " meses " + (total.Day % 365) + " dias.";
    }

    public string Imprimir_Experiencias_Trabalho()
    {
        return "<tr>"
                    + "<td>" + NomeEmpresa + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + Cargo + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + DescricaoFuncao + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + TempoTotal + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + "<i class='fa fa-edit'></i> <i class='fa fa-trash'></i>" + "</td>"
             + "</tr";
    }
}
```

Comment: Você só disse que está comp problemas. Especifique a dificuldade que está tendo. Tá tudo muito geral. O que não está dando certo? Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: Ok vou editar o texto

Comment: Não porque você não detalha esse erro. Sem informações completas fica difícil ajudar. Ninguém aqui está vendo o que você está vendo. Eu vou reescrever o código pra ele ficar mais simples e no estilo do C#, mas sem maiores informações não tenho como arrumar nenhum erro adicional que não esteja descrito na pergunta ou que seja muito aparente.

Comment: Inseri uma imagem com o erro, é isso o que acontece quando eu coloco pra imprimir o que eu quero.

Comment: Agora ficou fácil, a solução da interpolação é melhor e resolve este problema.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado, estou desde as 10 da manhã tentando resolver isso, só vim aqui porquê ja tinha lido as bilbiotecas do C# e não estava entendendo como arrumar isso. Eu queria saber onde vocês aprendem tão bem assim a sintaxe porquê na minha faculdade eu acho as explicações da sintaxe das linguagens muito rasas, isso acaba nos atrasando nesse erros =/.

Comment: Ainda seria melhor colocar na pergunta a descrição do erro como texto para ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo erro acharem a solução aqui quando *googlarem*.

Comment: vou colocar aqui então

Comment: Faculdade é um lugar para ensinar o conceito geral da computação, não para ensinar sintaxe. Isto se aprende estudando por conta própria e treinando.Mas sem a base, e isto a faculdade boa tem que dar, fica difícil estudar. Decorar sintaxe não é importante, entender bem como as coisas funcionam, porque funcionam é que importa. Aí pode se virar sozinho. Se decorar sintaxe vai sempre depender de alguém para resolver os problemas para você. Nenhum problema nisso quando está aprendendo, mas é um problemão se for "experiente" e ainda precisar de outras pessoas para qualquer coisa simples.

Comment: Se quiser aprender mais sobre C# tem várias formas, uma delas é ler as perguntas aqui nosite: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=50 As minhas costumas ser algumas das mais instrutivas (eu gosto de ensinar mais do que resolver o problema da pessoa, assim ela não precisa voltar sempre, não gosto de cliente cativo :) ): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20[c%23] Não se esqueça de votar em tudo o que achar útil.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, obrigado =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem vários problemas nesse código. Vou corrigir alguns.

O método `TempoTotal()` não precisa ser estático, não está havendo ganho algum em ser, pelo contrário, está trazendo problema.

É muito mais fácil criar propriedades automáticas e usá-las como um todo no código. Veja abaixo a enorme simplificação.

É melhor usar [interpolação de *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101) (bom, isso só funciona no C# 6 pra cima). Nesse caso não há necessidade de inicializar os campos, mas se fosse poderia fazer direto na propriedade.

Note como o código do método em questão pode ser mais simples:

```
public class Experiencias_Trabalho {
    public Experiencias_Trabalho(string nomeEmpresa, string cargo, string descricaoFuncao, DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataSaida) {
        NomeEmpresa = nomeEmpresa;
        Cargo = cargo;
        DescricaoFuncao = descricaoFuncao;
        DataInicio = dataInicio;
        DataSaida = dataSaida;
    }

    public string NomeEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string Cargo { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoFuncao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataSaida { get; set; }

    public string TempoTotal() {
        var total = new DateTime().AddDays((int)(DataSaida - DataInicio).TotalDays);
        return (total.Year - 1) + " anos, " + (total.Month % 12) + " meses " + (total.Day % 365) + " dias.";
    }

    public string Imprimir_Experiencias_Trabalho() {
        return $@"<tr>
                      <td>{NomeEmpresa}</td>
                      <td>{Cargo}</td>
                      <td>{DescricaoFuncao}</td>
                      <td>{TempoTotal()}</td>
                      <td><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> <i class='fa fa-trash'></i></td>
                  </tr>";
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/InterpolationOverConcatenation.cs).

Se não estiver usando versão do C# 5 ou anterior (não aconselho), ainda pode simplificar um pouco o método de impressão. Não pode usar o `$` da interpolação, mas pode usar o `@` do verbatim.

Idealmente uma classe não deveria ter um *underline* seguindo o [guia de estilo do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Assim como se no método `TempoTotal()` tivesse os parâmetros, eles deveriam ser nomeados em minúsculo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar arrumar aqui dessa maneira pra ver se fica melhor, obrigado Big.

Comment: Queria deixar uma dica bigown, quando os exemplos são curtos, como foi o caso do OP, uma ferramenta bastante útil para determinar onde está o erro é o [csharppad](http://csharppad.com/). Eu mesmo fui perguntar o erro mas depois lembrei-me desta ferramenta e removi o comentário.

Comment: @BrunoCosta legal. Mas de qualquer forma fica muito mais organizado a pessoa colocar o erro para depois outras pessoas com o mesmo erro poderem achar a solução.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que `Imprimir_Experiencias_Trabalho` tenta fazer uma concatenação com `TempoTotal`. `TempoTotal` é um método. Por este motivo você pode chamá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
TempoTotal(DataInicio, DataSaida);
```

Comment: O bug sumiu, parece que era isso msm que eu precisava fazer. Obrigado bruno. Agora vou arrumar a modelagem pra receber essas informações. Se a impressão dos dados sair correta eu marco aqui sua resposta como solução. Vlw msm