# Biblioteca que faça igual a interpolation string do C# 6.0 em tempo execução

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, string, interpolação-de-string

Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca que faça interpolação em de tempo de execução em strings?

Sei que seria possível fazer utilizando `Replace()`, mas não quero passar a lista com todas as variáveis.

Por exemplo:

```
Programa de classe
{
    const string interpolados = $ "{FirstName}"; 
    // variável *FirstName* não existe no contexto atual

     static void Main (string [] args)
     {
        var firstName = "fred";
        Console.WriteLine (interpolado);
        Console.ReadKey ();
     }
}
```

`interpolados` também pode ser um texto com varias variáveis.

Como fazer algo semelhante?

Comment: Relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29068642/221800

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é necessário biblioteca alguma, o .NET sempre teve este recurso. Na verdade a interpolação mostrada é nova e poucos conhecem. Essa é a primeira vez que encontro alguém que conhece o recurso novo e não o antigo.

Pode ser que não seja bem com a sintaxe que deseja, mas essa sintaxe para resolver em tempo de execução é até ruim e induz a erros e acopla nomes que nem sempre o código poderá garantir.

Tecnicamente é possível fazer uma biblioteca que aceite nomes de variáveis no lugar de números dos parâmetros, mas não vejo vantagens.

Note que o exemplo mostrado não é possível fazer nada porque teria que passar o parâmetro em tempo de execução. Na verdade nem mesmo usando a interpolação do C# 6 esse código funciona.

O que deseja é o que é feito com `string.Format()`. A mesma que sempre foi usada internamente em um `WriteLine()`, por exemplo.

```
var texto = string.Format("{0}", firstname);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ndu8M2). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HvLkRy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Format.cs).

A interpolação do C# 6 usa uma sintaxe mais simples com a ajuda do compilador. Eu falo sobre ele na pergunta [O que significa o simbolo "$" antes de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101)

Vou citar algumas bibliotecas, mas pense 10 vezes antes de adotá-las, pode parecer algo bom, mas não ser o que precisa. Não as conheço, não posso falar da qualidade delas:

- [SmartFormat.NET](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET)
- [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/)
- [Expansive](https://github.com/anderly/Expansive)
- [string_format](https://github.com/little-sharps/string_format)

Tem um [código no CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/109858/468) que pode servir de inspiração para fazer o próprio mecanismo (não é fácil pensar em tudo).

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado

Comment: Valeu, esse projeto resolveu o problema SO: https://github.com/little-sharps/string_format.

Comment: @bigown, mais uma altenativa: [Handlebars.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Handlebars.Net/)