# Como obter um valor usando interpolação?

Tags: c#, string, interpolação-de-string

Estou tentando recuperar um valor de uma classe usando interpolação. Usando   **`Console.WriteLine($"Meu Nome é,  {pessoa.Nome}");`**, obtenho o valor da forma que quero, mas no meu caso a `string` vai vir de uma configuração do banco de dados.

Tentei montar da seguinte forma

```
string expressao = "Meu Nome é,  {pessoa.Nome}";
```

e chamar assim

```
Console.WriteLine($"" + (expressao));
```

Isso imprime a string

> Meu Nome é,  {pessoa.Nome}

E isso não é o que quero. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
using System;

namespace Usando_Interpolacao
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pessoa = new Pessoa()
            {
                Documento = new Documento()
                {
                    Numero = 12345,
                    Tipo = "RG"
                },
                Idade = 20,
                Nome = "Papai Noel",
            };

            string expressao = "Meu Nome é,  {pessoa.Nome}";

            Console.WriteLine($"Meu Nome é,  {pessoa.Nome}"); // print --> Meu Nome é,  Papai Noel
            Console.WriteLine($"" + (expressao)); // print --> Meu Nome é,  {pessoa.Nome} .. Errado :(
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Pessoa
    {
        public int Idade { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public Documento Documento { get; set; }
    }

    public class Documento
    {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: e `expressao = $"Meu Nome é,  {pessoa.Nome}";` dps, `Console.WriteLine(expressao);` ?

Comment: Não tem como porque a interpolação é resolvida em tempo de compilação. Ou seja, os tokens precisam ser conhecidos de antemão. O código final é um `string.Format` padrão. O que você pode fazer é construir um método pra resolver os tokens dinamicamente.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que significa o simbolo “$” antes de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/18246)

Comment: Relacionada: [Biblioteca que faça igual a interpolation string do C# 6.0 em tempo execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136458/18246)

Comment: Você precisa de algo que faça o "parse" ou "evaluate" da sua expressão para isso. Dá uma olhada nesse pacote que faz exatamente isso: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: Com esse pacote, seu código ficaria assim: `var resultado = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(expressao);`

Comment: @LINQ, legal esse link do bigown, vou ver essas bibliotecas que ele deu de referencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o  [Smart.Format](https://github.com/axuno/SmartFormat.NET), não sei se é uma boa biblioteca, mas no momento atendo o que preciso.

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa()
{
    Documento = new Documento()
    {
        Numero = 12345,
        Tipo = "RG"
    },
    Idade = 20,
    Nome = "Papai Noel",
    Codigo = 1,
};

string expressao = "Pessoa/{Documento.Tipo}";
string texto = string.Empty;

texto = Smart.Format(expressao, pessoa);
Console.WriteLine(texto);
```

Comment: Essa biblioteca não resolve o problema da sua pergunta também?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, resolve sim. montou a string como eu queria.