# Converter valor de string para hexadecimal sem alterar formato

Tags: c#, .net, string, conversão-de-tipo, hexadecimal

Estou utilizando o seguinte código em uma Classe.

```
  public Int16 Endereco = 0x7302;
  byte[] Data = BitConverter.GetBytes(Endereco);
  Array.Reverse(Data);
  [...]
```

Gostaria de receber o valor para a variável `Endereco` de um `String`, que será obtido através da leitura de um formulário web. Como eu poderia receber a *string* e converter o mesmo numero para hexadecimal, por exemplo:

```
  String entrada = "7302";
```

Converter para Endereco como 0x7302, ou

```
 String entrada = "1A3B"
```

Converter para endereco como 0x1A3B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine($"{int.Parse("7302", NumberStyles.HexNumber):X}");
        WriteLine($"{int.Parse("1A3B", NumberStyles.HexNumber):X}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/V0ZEt8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3qMJOJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/StringHexadecimalToNumber.cs).

Se não tiver certeza que a *string* possui um número conversível corretamente então é melhor usar [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Int32__).

Obviamente que depois de converter a *string* para um número, ele é apenas isto, um número, não tem formatação, ele não é decimal ou hexadecimal, é só um número. Se deseja vê-lo como hexadecimal precisa mandar imprimir assim e foi o que eu fiz no `WriteLine()`. Usei [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101) com [formatação (o `:X`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads). Assim imprime uma representação hexadecimal do número. Se não usar desta forma o padrão é imprimir o valor em representação decimal.

Se não quiser imprimir, só para converter é isto:

```
int.Parse("1A3B", NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou para o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você receba uma string representando o endereço em hexadecimal.
O caminho mais indicado seria primeiramente converter esta string para um valor inteiro, algo que pode não ser trivial. 
Com o numero convertido em inteiro, o hexadecimal sera apenas a representação do valor:
String 1A3B = 6715, logo 6715 == 0x1A3B.