# Converter int para hex

Tags: c#, int, hexadecimal

o que eu to querendo fazer é possível? converter a variável value para hex.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int value = 255;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
        buffer[0] = 0xff;
        buffer[1] = value; //eu preciso converter esse value para hex.
                           //igual ao buffer[0] , tem como?    
}
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que deseja fazer, você quer imprimir o valor em hexadecimal? Hexadecimal é só uma representação, número é número, não precisa de conversão.

Comment: Seria o mesmo que aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181044/101

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, consegui fazer o que queria.

Answer (score 1):

```
int intValue = 182;

string hexValue = intValue.ToString("X");

int intAgain = int.Parse(hexValue,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Valor `decimal` para `hexadecimal` utilize [ToString("X")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#XFormatString):

```
int value = 255;
string hexValue = value.ToString("X");
```

*Saída:*

```
FF
```

[***Exemplo***](http://ideone.com/BKcBHx)

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Cadeias de caracteres de formato numérico padrão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#XFormatString)
- [Método Int32.ToString ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx)