# Exceção sem tratamento (índice baseado em 0)

Tags: c#, .net, string

Minha ideia é fazer um pequeno cadastro e estou testando isso para, mais tarde adicionar esses dados em um BD. O problema ocorre na linha `Console.Write("\nGenero do disco : {1}", genero);`, na hora de exibir a *string* lida via teclado. Segue o erro:

> Exceção sem tratamento
>   System.FormatException: 'Índice (baseado em zero) deve ser maior ou igual a zero e menor que o tamanho da lista de argumentos.'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Cadastro_de_músicas
{
    class Disco
    {
        public string nome;
        public string genero;
        public string ano;

        public void cadastra()
        {
            Console.Write("Digite o nome do disco: ");
            nome = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Digite o genero do disco: ");
            genero = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Digite o ano do disco: ");
            ano = Console.ReadLine();
        }

            public void exibe()
            {
            Console.Write("Nome do disco: {0}", nome);
            Console.Write("\nGenero do disco : {1}", genero);
            Console.Write("\nAno do disco: {2}", ano);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um jeito mais moderno de fazer isso que não causa este tipo de erro. Faça uso de [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101), é muito melhor. Aproveitei e melhorei outras coisas. Veja [padrões de nomenclatura usados em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Tem outras coisas que podem ser melhoras neste código, mas vamos parar por aqui.

```
using static System.Console;
 
namespace CadastroDeMusicas {
    public class Disco {
        public static string nome;
        public static string genero;
        public static string ano;
 
        public static void Main() {
            Write("Digite o nome do disco: ");
            nome = ReadLine();
            Write("Digite o genero do disco: ");
            genero = ReadLine();
            Write("Digite o ano do disco: ");
            ano = ReadLine();
            Exibe();
        }
 
        public static void Exibe() {
            WriteLine($"Nome do disco: {nome}");
            WriteLine($"Genero do disco : {genero}");
            WriteLine($"Ano do disco: {ano}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0p1JL8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ISlRQJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Interpolation.cs).

Comment: A interpolação resolveu meu problema, embora não tenha ficado muito claro como rs Eu comecei com .NET essa semana e, pra falar a verdade, deveria estar me concentrando mais no aprendizado da POO do que nesses detalhes. Mas sabe como é a curiosidade , né ? ;D

Comment: Eu já acho o contrário, são esses detalhes q fazem vc aprender mesmo (ñ só esse, claro). OOP é superestimado e no fundo quase todo mundo aprende errado, então pra que pressa pra aprender errado? :D Tem o *link* lá falando mais sobre a interpolação.

Answer (score 5):

Quando a escrita é feita com as chavetas, estas indicam o numero do elemento a escrever. Por isso esta linha:

```
Console.Write("\nGenero do disco : {1}", genero);
```

Deveria ser:

```
Console.Write("\nGenero do disco : {0}", genero);
```

Deve ser `{0}` porque é o primeiro elemento a escrever da lista de elementos.

Se colocar duas variaveis na mesma escrita, ai sim usa numeros `{0}` e `{1}`, assim:

```
Console.Write("\nBom dia {0}, {1}", apelido, primeiroNome);
```

O mesmo erro acontece na ultima escrita para a consola.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Embora eu, como disse acima, não tenha entendido muito bem alguns detalhes. Por exemplo: "Quando a escrita é feita com as chavetas, estas indicam o numero do elemento a escrever. Por isso esta linha:" Esse número do elemento seria a posição dele na memória ? Temos 3 elementos : 1 - nome , 2 - gênero e 3 - ano..Gênero seria o segundo elemento ao invés do primeiro, não ?

Mais uma vez, obrigado :D

Comment: A sua lógica está certa mas há um pormenor, os elementos começam sempre no 0 e não no 1. Da mesma forma que um array de elementos começa na posição 0. Por isso o primeiro elemento é na verdade o elemento 0, e assim sucessivamente

Comment: O número entre as chavetas indica a posição do elemento _na lista de argumentos passada para o_ `String.Format()` _ou_ `Console.Write()`. O primeiro argumento é a _string_ de formatação, depois os elementos a interpolar: 0, 1, 2, e assim por diante, tantos quanto você precisar passar.