# É possível omitir os números dos argumentos de formatação do "String.Format" em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Eu estava vendo que em Python é possível [formatar uma *string* sem numerar os argumentos](https://repl.it/@wallacemaxters/String-Format-Python-Sem-numeracao).

Exemplo:

```
#mensagem = "Meu nome é {0} e minha idade é {1}";

mensagem = "Meu nome é {} e minha idade é {}".format("Wallace", 27)

print(mensagem);
```

Existe alguma forma em Csharp de definir os argumentos da formatação de maneira posicional (isto é, omitindo o número, da mesma forma que no Python)?

## Edit

Eu preciso de algo parecido no C#. Seria muito útil em um cenário onde eu preciso concatenar strings que precisarão ser formatadas, porém as numerações dos argumentos precisaria ser dinâmica.

Exemplo:

```
  var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
          {"AND [a] = {0} ", TB_A.Text},
          {"AND [b] LIKE '%{1}%' ", TB_B.Text},
          {"AND [c] = '{2}' ", TB_C.Text},
          {"AND [d] = '{3}' ", TB_D.Text}
    };

    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        // Se o valor for vazio, pula
        // Isso quebra a sequência?
        if (parameter.Value.Length > 0)
        {
            retorno += parameter.Key;
        }
    }

    DataSource.FilterExpression = retorno;

    DataSource.FilterParameters.Clear();

    DataSource.FilterParameters.Add("A", TB_A.Text);
    DataSource.FilterParameters.Add("B", TB_B.Text);
    DataSource.FilterParameters.Add("C", TB_C.Text);
    DataSource.FilterParameters.Add("D", TB_D.Text);
```

Dessa forma atualmente, quando eu tenho `{1}`, mas não tenho `{0}`, a "formatação" para o valor de `{1}` está sendo ignorada. Fiz uns testes e percebi que, se ele obedecer a uma ordem posicional certinha (ex: 0,1,2,3), funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Depois de marcar como duplicada eu percebi que talvez não seja. O que você acha, AP?

Comment: Não acho que seja. Eu preciso por exemplo de montar uma string mais ou menos com concatenação, porém não dá pra "advininhar" qual condição será aceita ou não pra concatentar. Por isso a ideia era concatenar com  "AND x = {}" para depois usar o `DS_Grid.FilterParameters.Add` com o número de argumentos certos (pois jogando como qualquer número tá dando erro).

Comment: Acho que sua dúvida deveria ser voltada para o problema específico. Da forma atual tá bem com cara de duplicada da que eu apontei.

Comment: @LINQ de qualquer forma, a pergunta referência da duplicação não responde a respeito do "argumento posicional dinâmico", no sentido de ela ignorar o número e pegar pela primeira ocorrência em diante do `{}`. De toda forma, o "não" do Maniero já respondeu.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Era isso? Precisa mais?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Era isso? Precisa mais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, mas pode fazer [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101):

```
mensagem = $"Meu nome é {("Wallace")} e minha idade é {27}";
```

Claro que se não for variável ou alguma expressão que envolva variável, não faz sentido.

Respondendo à edição:

```
public class Program { public static void Main() => System.Console.WriteLine("{0}, {2}, {3}", 1, null, "teste", 23.5); }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BEkkZT). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CQ7t7G). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SkipParameter.cs).

Ainda acho esta solução horrível, não deveria montar *queries* assim. Anos de gambiarra em PHP dá nisso :P

Aprender fazer MCVE é bom :P

Comment: Os valores foram só um exemplo, mas a ideia era a variável mesmo. E no meu caso, o problema é que a classe que faz o controle da formatação é o `ParameterCollection` do `SqlDataSource`. Mas o "não" já ajuda a saber que vou ter que ir por outro caminho, kkkkkk