# Tem função format() da linguagem Python em C#?

Tags: c#, python, .net, string

```
int varvalor;
int var01 = varvalor * 1;
Console.Write("Digite um número para ser multiplicado: ");
var01 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();
```

Eu queria escrever no `Console.WriteLine();` estas linhas de código que se escreve em Python.

```
varvalor = int(input("Digite um número para ser multiplicado: "))
var01 = varvalor * 1
print("{} x 1 = {}".format(varvalor, var01))
```

Há alguma forma de fazer isto em C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo vários problemas nesses códigos, mas sem entrar nesse mérito e só para responder a sua dúvida, pode fazer assim:

```
$"{varvalor} x 1 = {var01}"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/VarVar.php).

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero