# É possível interpolar uma string já declarada em C#?

Tags: c#, string

A pergunta [O que significa o simbolo “$” antes de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91117)
, explica que é possível fazer interpolação de strings em C# através do `$` (cifrão).

Porém percebi que, em todos os casos onde é usado, a sintaxe funciona para strings diretamente declaradas, assim:

```
   string nome = "Wallace Maxters";

   $"Meu nome é {nome}";
```

Porém eu precisava fazer algo assim, utilizando uma string já existente. Quero dizer, eu já tenho uma string pronta e quero usá-la com o  `$` posteriormente à declaração.

Exemplo aproximado:

```
 string template = "Meu nome é {nome}";

 usarTemplate(template); // Faz a mesma coisa que o $ fez no exemplo anterior
```

Seria possível aplicar o mesmo efeito do `$` em na `string` `template`, posteriormente?

**Atualização**

O que desejo fazer seria mais ou menos parecido com que o `String.Format` já faz, porém queria com os parâmetros nomeados.

Comment: Você deseja "declarar uma variável" nela e mudar depois?

Comment: @Barbetta sim, mais ou menos igual é possível fazer com `String.Format`. Por exemplo: `String.Format(stringExistente, valor1, valor2)`

Answer (score 0):

A resposta rápida: não pode. A interpolação de `string` (`$`) funciona no imediato, não é possível fazê-la dinamicamente.

Se utilizar o `string.Format("{0}")` sim, aí já pode fazer coisas mais "engraçadas".

Comment: Não ajudaria muito. O `String.Format` funciona por parametrização sequencial. Isso seria um inferno para fazer um template de Email,por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, é sequencial, é uma das "desvantagens".