# SHA512 retorno em hexadecimal

Tags: c#, .net, string, criptografia, conversão

Encontrei um exemplo de criptografar uma *string* com SHA512.

```
public static string HashedString(string text)
{
    SHA512Managed sha512 = new SHA512Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte b in hash)
        result.Append(b);

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Porém quando mando imprimir na tela o retorno desse método percebo que o resultado é em binário e eu quero em hexadecimal.

Comment: E qual sua dúvida?

Comment: PQ o resuldato do método não é como no exemplo?

Comment: E porque deveria?

Comment: Maniero eu espero receber o resultado como o do exemplo. Se você for em qualquer gerador de sha512 online, como [esse](http://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha512/) por exemplo, o resultado que você receberá é uma string como a do exemplo.
O que falta ou o que está errado código para que eu possa obter um resultado igual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso?

```
public static string HashedString(string text) {
    var sha512 = new SHA512Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in hash) result.Append($"{b:x2}");
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MGRczr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EfzQZC). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ConvertToHex.cs).

Precisa dizer que quer em hexadecimal se é isto que deseja. Veja [O que significa o simbolo "$" antes de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101).

Comment: Ummm, converter byte por byte em string. Pode realmente ser isso, só não estou muito familiarizado com a string que vc passou para o método Append()

Comment: Quando via o resultado pensei que poderia ser hexa mas não tinha certeza, pensei que poderia ser apenas uma sequencia aleatória de números e letras geradas pelo algoritmo de criptografia, até pq não havia lido sobre como funciona o processo de hash sha512. Vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Onde está

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in hash)
    result.Append(b);

return result.ToString();
```

substitua por

```
return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
```

Dessa forma, você não terá n+1 strings no heap, mas só 2.