# Criar um programa que faça sorteio de 6 números e apresente depois quantas vezes foi sorteado

Tags: c#, .net, array, random

Estou fazendo um programa que sorteie 6 números (1 ao 6) 1 milhão de vezes e no final apresente quantas vezes foi sorteado, porém estou com uma dúvida no código, estou otimizando em vetores para não usar `if`, porém no final ele está considerando a posição 0 do vetor e o número 0 e acaba não sorteando o número 6, somente do 0 ao 5, podem me ajudar a ver o que está de errado?

Segue o código em C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            int[] numeros;
            numeros = new int[6];
            int randnum;
            Random rdm = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)

            {

                randnum = rdm.Next(6);
                Console.WriteLine("girei pela: " + i + " vez");

                numeros[randnum] = numeros[randnum] + 1;

            }


            for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Quantidade de vezes que o N° "+i+ " foi sorteado: " + numeros[i]);

            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É só somar 1:

```
randnum = rdm.Next(6) + 1;
```

O gerador de códigos gera um número de 0 até logo antes do número que colocou no método `Next()`. É como um *array*, o número que coloca ali não conta. Como você também não quer o 0 é só somar 1, então o que estava dando de 0 à 5 passa gerar de 1 à 6.

Só que analisando melhor o código nem é o caso de fazer isso. Você só deveria somar um na apresentação. Explico: o *array* vai de 0 à 5, e você está sorteando esses números, então já está correto. Na hora de apresentar o que está no índice 0 você quer considerar que é o número 1, e o que está em 1 quer que mostre como 2, assim por diante até o último elemento do *array*  que é 5 e você quer apresentar como 6 sorteado.

E dá para otimizar algumas coisas no código.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            var numeros = new int[6];
            var rdm = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1_000_000; i++) {
                WriteLine($"girei pela: {i}a. vez");
                numeros[rdm.Next(6)]++;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++) WriteLine($"Quantidade de vezes que o N° {i + 1} foi sorteado: {numeros[i]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/B2HWwX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1hzcss). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/RandomRange.cs).

Comment: Caramba, consegui entender! Muito obrigado pela ajuda... estou entrando nessa linguagem agora e estou me aprofundando. Essa parte que você colocou "1_000_000" separado, é para melhor leitura do número apenas? Qual é a função do "$" antes do texto?

Comment: Sim, usei separador pra dar mais legibilidade. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101