# Como devo atribuir strings no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho

Até aonde sei, `System.String` no .NET (não sei se em outras plataformas o tipo string também é assim) é imutável, ou seja, se eu fizer:

```
string a = "texto";
a = "outro texto";
```

Por detrás dos panos, ao atribuir outro texto em `a`, ele vai criar outra instancia de `a`. É isso mesmo ou estou falando algo equivocado?

Existem algumas partes do código aqui na empresa com o seguinte cenário:

```cs
private void Cadastrar(string Valor, string Valor2, string Valor3)
{
    string msg = "";
    try
    {       
        Entidade obj = new Entidade();
        DAL objDal = new DAL();

        msg = "Campo 1";
        obj.Campo1 = Valor;

        msg = "Campo 2";
        obj.Campo2 = Valo2;

        msg = "Campo 3";
        obj.Campo3 = Valor3;

        objDal.Cadastrar(obj);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string errmsg = "Erro ao cadastrar o campo " + msg;
        MessageBox.Show(errmsg);
    }
}
```

Eu imagino que a atribuição das strings deveria ser a menor das minhas preocupações nesse cenário, mas existe alguma forma de eu conseguir melhorar as atribuições dessas strings ou isso é frescura da minha parte?

A minha preocupação é que isso acontece em vários lugares e creio que isso poderá ser um peso desnecessário na aplicação e que pode ser corrigido ou melhorado de alguma forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Por detrás dos panos, ao atribuir outro texto em a, ele vai criar outra instância de `a`. É isso mesmo ou estou falando algo equivocado?

Não exatamente, neste exemplo está "criando" outra instância, mas nem sempre isso é verdade, atribuir um valor a uma variável e criar instância são coisas distintas. Embora essa instância específica já esteja no executável, então criar também não é bem o termo. Literais do tipo `string` já estão todos criados quando inicia a execução da aplicação, uma instância só é criada em nova área de memória quando o dado vem externamente ou é construído em tempo de execução.

> Eu imagino que a atribuição das *strings* deveria ser a menor das minhas preocupações nesse cenário

Não sei, eu me preocupo bastante, e entendo todo funcionamento da memória do .NET para tomar as decisões certas.

> mas existe alguma forma de eu conseguir melhorar as atribuições dessas *strings* ou isso é frescura da minha parte?

Vale meu primeiro comentário. Pode ter um jeito melhor de fazer esse mecanismo que criou como um todo (inclusive porque é uso errado de exceção, mas não vem ao caso aqui), mas feito desta forma não tem como reduzir a quantidade de instâncias de texto existentes. Exceto talvez a concatenação de *strings* dentro de exceção, mas é como falei, esse erro só existe porque o uso de exceção está errado.

Quando concatena duas *strings* está criando uma terceira, então prefira uma [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101), o ganho pode não ser grande, mas pode valer a pena.

Não afeta nada no  que está perguntando, mas poderia afetar outro caso, por que criou uma variável  que só é usada uma vez? Em geral isso é um equívoco.

> A minha preocupação é que isso acontece em vários lugares.

Isso pode ser um problema, tudo o que acontece em vários lugares tender a ser o mecanismo errado e provavelmente viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Comment: Pelo que entendi, utilizar StringBuilder não iria ajudar muito, certo? O problema é muito maior, ou seja, no conceito e não simplesmente eu trocar A por B.

Comment: Neste caso, zero, ou seria negativo.