# Como apresento uma variável do tipo número na tela com C#?

Tags: c#, .net, console

Quero exibir uma variável do tipo número, mas ao fazer isso dá o seguinte erro:

> ```
> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'
> ```

Meu código:

```
int[] array = new int[3];
        int menorNumero = 0;
        int meioNumero = 0;
        int maiorNumero = 0;
        int slot;
        
      int size = array.Length;

      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        array[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
          if(menorNumero > meioNumero){
              slot = meioNumero;
              meioNumero = menorNumero;
              menorNumero = slot;
          }
          
          if(meioNumero > maiorNumero) {
              slot = maiorNumero;
              maiorNumero = meioNumero;
              meioNumero = slot;
          }
      }
      Console.WriteLine(menorNumero, meioNumero, maiorNumero);
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro leia: [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Sempre que não sabe como usar algo, procure a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Consegue ver ali uma opção com 3 `int`s? Não tem, não dá para colocar tudo o que pode ser combinado. Tem algumas poucas opções como otimização para casos simples e depois uma forma que trata de objetos de qualquer tipo. E aí tem que começar com uma `string`. Mas não qualquer texto pode ser usado, é uma *string* de formatação, conforme pode ser vista na [documentação específica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#system-console-writeline(system-string-system-object-system-object-system-object)) onde mostra o uso de [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101).

O erro se dá porque o melhor que ele consegue achar é um caso em que só funcionaria se converter de `int` para `string`, mesmo assim o resultado não seria o esperado, porque ele espera a formatação ali e não um número.

```
WriteLine($"Menor número: {menorNumero} Do meio: {meioNumero} Maior número: {maiorNumero}");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/Syntax.cs).

Claro que ainda poderia usar uma opção que aceita uma *string* simples, para isso precisaria concatenar o que deseja, mas teria que usar *strings*, e não vale a pena converter para isto.

Além disso o código pode ser muito mais simples, se não for obrigado por alguma razão artificial fazer desta forma.

Answer (score -1):

A função Console.Writeline tem várias escritas. Porém em nenhuma delas é possível receber 3 inteiros e pintar os mesmos na tela.

Para resolver isso, você precisa utilizar a interpolação, e com C# você tem diferentes formas de fazer isso.

É possível você utilizar o $ na frente da string e interpolar variáveis utilizando {} dentro dela:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Menor número: {menorNumero} Do meio: {meioNumero} Maior número: {maiorNumero}");
```

É possível também você fazer a interpolação utilizando a sobrecarga da Console.WriteLine que espera receber uma string e um array de argumentos. Você utiliza o índice do valor que foi passado como argumento entre { }, dessa forma seu exemplo seria da seguinte forma:

```
Console.WriteLine("Menor número: {0} Do meio: {1} Maior número: {2}", menorNumero, meioNumero, maiorNumero);
```

É possível também simplesmente somar o valor da variável na string (**lembrando que isso não é uma boa prática**):

```
Console.WriteLine("Menor número: "+menorNumero+" Do meio: "+meioNumero+" Maior número: "+maiorNumero);
```