# Interpolação de string nao retorna pelo indexador em c#

Tags: c#, array

Sabemos que a interpolação de string usado no c# são válidos de acordo com cada indexador usador na aplicação. No exemplo abaixo estou declarando uma aplicação simples usando duas variáveis e um double para retornar informações usando indexadores. Contudo ao imprimir no console o mesmo não retornam os valores atribuídos as variáveis, onde estou errando?

```cs
string nome = "Notebook";
string marca = "Dell";
double preco = 5800.00;
Console.WriteLine($"O {0} da marca {1} custa {2}.", nome, marca, preco);
```

Comment: testou removendo o `$`?

Comment: Talvez duplicada de: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/628/como-substituir-vars-em-uma-string/43514#43514. Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91117/o-que-significa-o-simbolo-antes-de-uma-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Da forma usada é erro de digitação, porque se usar o $ os itens irão procurar valores no escopo ao invés dos parâmetros do WriteLine, está misturando duas maneiras sem necessidade, com o $ você poderá resolver todas variáveis diretamente sem precisar "numerar" pelos parâmetros.

Comment: Remova o "$" da declaração do começo da String.

A forma como você declarou os indexadores dentro da String, assinando os índices a uma váriavel no final, isso não é interpolaçao de caracter, é formatação composta. E formatação composta, só funciona sem a utilização do sinal de "$" no começo do String. E Interpolação de String, não tem a necessidades das váraveis no final.

Interporalação de String é:
**Console.WriteLine($"O {nome} da marca {marca} custa {preco}.");**

Formatação Composta é:
**Console.WriteLine("O {0} da marca {1} custa {2}.", nome, marca, preco);**

Comment: ok pessoal, estarei realizando os procedimento de retirada de $ para imprimir as informações no terminal.

Comment: Retornando, o procedimento de retirada do $ imprimiu as informações no terminal.

Comment: Faltou explicar: 1 - `Console.WriteLine("O {0} da marca {1} custa {2}.", nome, marca, preco);` ou 2 `Console.WriteLine($"O {nome} da marca {marca} custa {preco}.");` tente entender o porque não funcionou e não somente porque funcionou. Resumindo você usou errado a interporlação no seu código, então, eu passei a forma 2 com interpolação para sua observação.